# Woocommerce Automatically turn off stock management

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is there a possible way to automatically turn off stock management when product quantity = 0? 
I'm using woocommerce and using product stock quantity as a way to display availability in physical store. When product is completely sold, then you cann't go and buy that product in store, but you can still buy it online. So the problem is, variable text that shows that "product in showroom" is attached to stock management,and i want automatically turn off stock management when product is sold.

Comment: You should better **enable/allow "backorders"** when stock management is enabled at product level. This way the customer can buy items that are normally "out of stock". There is 2 ways for backorders: one with a front end notification, the other without front end notification… This is the right way to do it normally.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Thank you! Worked.